How to make MDDialog in kivymd 2.0.1 bigger in height
I have a custom MDDialog with a scrollview inside of it. The problem is that the dialog is very small. When I remove the scrollview, the dialog (because of the amount of data it must display) is too large to fit into the screen (this is why I added the scrollview). How do I make the dialog bigger but not too big.
Results with the scrollview
Results without the scrollview
When running the code below and pressing the MDIconButton with the information icon you will see the MDDialog. When pressing the button next to it - the program will crash because thats not where the problem is.
The 2 directories the MDDialog takes its data from is

Exercises. There are files of each exercise (I will provide only 1 file):

Выпад.txt:
"""
None
10
Улучшение осанки (снятие боли со спины)
Время
hip_flexor_stretch.jpg

На коврике для йоги или коврике для упражнений встаньте на оба колена. Ваши ягодицы должны находиться на пятках ног, а подушечки ног плотно прижиматься к коврику.
Наклонитесь вперед и прижмите ладони к коврику. Руки должны быть на ширине плеч, а локти слегка согнуты, чтобы предотвратить их блокирование.
Вытяните левое колено вперед через промежуток между руками и поставьте левую ногу на коврик перед собой, образуя угол в 90 градусов.
Выпрямите верхнюю часть тела и положите обе руки на левое колено перед собой для поддержки и равновесия.
Вытяните правую ногу позади себя. Правое колено должно быть прижато к коврику, а верхняя часть правой стопы должна лежать на коврике.
Слегка наклонитесь вперед, чтобы углубить растяжку. Удерживайте 20-30 секунд.
Выйдите из растяжки и повторите с другой стороны.
"""


Images. Here's an image for you to use when testing:

This is an image to use
Here is the code:
    from os import path, listdir

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDButton, MDButtonText
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog, MDDialogIcon, MDDialogHeadlineText, MDDialogButtonContainer, \
    MDDialogContentContainer
from kivymd.uix.divider import MDDivider
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.list import MDListItem
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.scrollview import MDScrollView

exercise_items = [x.replace('.txt', '') for x in listdir('exercises')]

Builder.load_string("""

<CustomOneLineIconListItem>
    MDListItemLeadingIcon:
        icon: "star-four-points-small"
    MDListItemSupportingText:
        text: root.text
    MDIconButton:
        icon: "information"
        theme_icon_color: "Custom"
        on_press: app.get_running_app().root.get_screen("Fourth").make_info_popup(root)
    MDButton:
        on_press: 
            # Basically, this gets the previous_screen variable (which is also a screen) of the FourthScreen, which in 
            # turn calls its add_exercise function
            # Yes, this is an abomination. I know that.
            previous_screen_var = app.get_running_app().root.get_screen("Fourth").previous_screen
            app.get_running_app().root.get_screen(previous_screen_var).add_exercise(root)
            app.change_to_screen(previous_screen_var)
        MDButtonIcon:
            icon: "plus"
        MDButtonText:
            text: "Add exercise"

<PreviousExercises>
    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: dp(10)
        padding: dp(20)

        MDBoxLayout:
            adaptive_height: True
            spacing: "5dp"

            MDIconButton:
                icon: 'arrow-left-bold'
                on_press: app.sm.current = 'Third'

            MDIconButton:   
                icon: 'magnify'

            MDTextField:
                id: search_field
                on_text: root.set_list_md_icons(self.text, True)
                MDTextFieldHintText:
                    text: 'Поиск Упражнения'
        RecycleView:
            id: rv
            key_viewclass: 'viewclass'
            key_size: 'height'

            RecycleBoxLayout:
                padding: dp(10)
                default_size: None, dp(48)
                default_size_hint: 1, None
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
                orientation: 'vertical'
""")


class FourthScreen(MDScreen):
    previous_screen = None

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FourthScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def make_info_popup(self, widget):
        filename = widget.text + ".txt"
        file = open(path.join('exercises', filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        s_name, rest_time, muscles, exc_type, image, *instructions = file.readlines()

        s_name = str(s_name)
        muscles = str(muscles)
        exc_type = str(exc_type)
        lbl_text = [str(s_name), str(exc_type), str(muscles)]
        for instruction in instructions:
            lbl_text.append(instruction)
        for x in lbl_text:
            x = x.replace("\n", "")
        file.close()

        self.dialog = MDDialog(
            MDDialogIcon(icon='information'),
            MDDialogHeadlineText(text="Информация о упражнении"),
            CustomMDDialogContentContainer(info=lbl_text, image=image, size_hint=(1, 1)
                                           ),
            MDDialogButtonContainer(
                Widget(),
                MDButton(
                    MDButtonText(text="Отмена"),
                    on_press=self.on_cancel_button_press),
                spacing="8dp"),
            size_hint=(1, 1))
        self.dialog.open()

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        main_widget = PreviousExercises()
        self.add_widget(main_widget)
        main_widget.set_list_md_icons()

    def on_cancel_button_press(self, instance):
        self.dialog.dismiss()

    def set_previous_screen(self, screen):
        self.previous_screen = screen


class CustomMDDialogContentContainer(MDDialogContentContainer):
    def __init__(self, *args, info, image, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.orientation = "vertical"
        layout_root = MDScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, size_hint_y=None)
        layout = MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical", size_hint=(1, None), adaptive_height=True,
                             padding="10dp", spacing="10dp")
        layout.add_widget(MDDivider())

        img = FitImage(source=path.join("images", image.replace("\n", "")), size_hint=(1, None),
                       keep_ratio=True, allow_stretch=True, height="300dp")
        layout.add_widget(img)
        layout.add_widget(MDDivider())
        for text_item in info:
            layout.add_widget(MDLabel(text=text_item, size_hint_y=None, adaptive_height=True))
        layout.add_widget(MDDivider())
        layout_root.add_widget(layout)
        self.add_widget(layout_root)


class CustomOneLineIconListItem(MDListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()
    text = StringProperty()


class PreviousExercises(MDScreen):
    def set_list_md_icons(self, text="", search=False):
        """Builds a list of exercises for the FourthScreen."""

        def add_exercise_item(name_exercise):
            self.ids.rv.data.append(
                {
                    "viewclass": "CustomOneLineIconListItem",
                    "text": name_exercise,
                    "callback": lambda x: x,
                }
            )

        self.ids.rv.data = []
        for name_exercise in exercise_items:
            if search:
                if text in name_exercise:
                    add_exercise_item(name_exercise)
            else:
                add_exercise_item(name_exercise)

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.sm = MDScreenManager()
        self.sm.add_widget(FourthScreen(name="Fourth"))
        return self.sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()


You can try setting the height of the MDScrollView to the height of the App. In your CustomMDDialogContentContainer.__init__() change:
    layout_root = MDScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, size_hint_y=None)

to:
    app = MDApp.get_running_app()
    layout_root = MDScrollView(do_scroll_x=False, do_scroll_y=True, size_hint_y=None, height=app.root.height)

